# Unable to record stereo audio using MediaRecorder

Tags: android, audio, video, mediarecorder, android-camera2

I am using sample video recording [app](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Video) which uses Camera2 API. In this sample, [MediaRecorder](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediarecorder.html) is used to set properties like audio source, video source etc.

I tried to record stereo audio(connected a stereo microphone to phone) by using `mediaRecorder.setAudioChannels(2)` but the meta data of the recorded file shows MONO channel only.

```
    mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE);
    mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
    mediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
    mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
    mediaRecorder.setVideoSize(videoSize.getWidth(), videoSize.getHeight());
    mediaRecorder.setAudioChannels(2);
```

I tested in Motorola Nexus 6.